# Make child div take max height

Tags: html, css, height, stretch

I'm trying to make the `.box-content` `div` take the max height there is left inside boxA/boxB `div`. I got a `div` `.box-header` and a `.box-content` inside boxA/boxB `div`. The `.box-content` is sharing a `div` with the `.box-header`.

In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sLcZ/10/) you can see that the `.box-content` is going outside it's parent `div`.

How can I solve this with pure CSS taking in account with these 2 rules:

1. The height of the `.box-content` is stretchable (grow/shrink
   whenever window size changes);
2. The `.box-content` has a minimum height of 200px;

Comment: I don't get the point of including bootstrap and not using it.

Comment: `.container` is from bootstrap :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `overflow` is an option (which i feel makes your life easy here), here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/6sLcZ/12/)

Keeping HTML same, your **css** (2 line changes) below

```
.boxA {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 0px 3px 5px 5px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    overflow:hidden; /*added this*/
}

.boxB {
    width: 420px;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 3px;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
    overflow:hidden;/*added this*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are facing is :

`.box-content` is set to 100% of it's parent but there is also the `.box-header` that is inside the parent so `.box-content` is pushed down and has to overflow (the size of `.box-content`) to keep 100% height of it's parent.

I can suggest this css :

```
.box-content { height: 90%; }

.box-header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    padding:11px 8px 5px;
    color: white;
    height:10%;
}
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6sLcZ/13/)**

Comment: updated the fiddle (forgot a coma that bugged the responsive height)

Comment: I knew that, but it was to illustrate what I was trying to accomplish :D got to say that the header needs to be fixed. A stretchable header looks very ugly. Thanks for your help! +1

Answer (score 2):

You could set the parent divs to be scrollable in the event that the child div has a bigger height.

`.boxA{ overflow:auto; }`
`.boxB{ overflow:auto; }`